# Differential of a function that takes values in a submanifold of Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

When I am trying to compute concretely in differential geometry I sometimes have a function $f\colon M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ let's say, where $M$ is a smooth manifold, but actually the image of $f$ lies in a familiar submanifold $\widetilde{M}$ like the sphere. It usually feels easier to compute the differential in coordinates of $f$ treating $f$ as a function with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but when I later want to understand $f$ as a function from $M$ to $\widetilde{M}$, my Jacobian in coordinates is now the wrong size because we treated $f$ as taking values in the $n$-dimensional manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of the smaller dimensional manifold $\widetilde{M}$. Is there a way to recover the differential of $f$ as a function taking values in $\widetilde{M}$ from this bigger differential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a map from $M$ to a sphere $S$. Now $S$ has some charts and coordinate systems.  There are no clear agreements to what each means, in the sense of : which way do they go: from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, or the other way. However, call them what you want, you have a map $\chi \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to V \subset S^2$, $(\phi, \theta) \mapsto ( \cos \theta \cos \phi, \cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta)$. Now, one sees that $\chi$ maps in fact into $\mathbb{R}^3$.  OK.

Now consider a map from $M$ to the sphere. You can think of it as a map from $F\colon M \to U$ ( at least locally). The actual map to the sphere will be $f =\chi \circ F$.  Now can you see how the jacobians of $f$ and $F$ are related?

Comment: Ah, so the chain rule plus $\chi$ being a diffeomorphism gives $df = d\chi \circ dF \implies d\chi^{-1} \circ df = dF$, and $dF$ is what I care about I think.

Comment: @E G: Yes Sir, it is the chain rule there.

Comment: Thank you this clarified things for me. At first I was annoyed by the fact that inverting $\chi$ in e.g. spherical coordinates is kind of tricky, but then I realized I was sort of hung up on this conceptually and I should use a nice basis for the tangent space when it arises instead of writing everything in terms of $\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z$.

Comment: @E G: Even on $\mathbb{R}^3$ you have spherical coordinates ( $r$ also is used). How about calculating in this system to see how it works ( like the lapplacian). Even in $R^2$ for polar coordinates. Good luck!